# Uninstall OpenZFSonOSX on OS 10.10?

Tags: kernel-panic, macos, zfs

I installed OpenZFSonOSX even though it is not compatible with OS X 10.10.
The zfs commands are not working and make the Mac to restart immediately.

I tried "uninstall-openzfsonosx.sh". It causes a kernel panic either.

Comment: 10.10.what? You might be falling foul of the unsigned kext 'protection' from 10.10.0 to 10.10.3 & did you read https://openzfsonosx.org/wiki/Install ?

Comment: 10.10.5. yes i read it. it was the official release (1.3.1-r2)